# How can I make Windows stop updating my broken shortcuts?

Tags: windows

When I click on a shortcut that doesn't exist, Windows opens a dialog (on WinXP) asking me to find the location, and in Win7 automatically does this (this is my observation).

I don't want my shortcuts to be updated.  I believe there was a registry hack to turn this behavior off, but I can't find the information on how to do this.

Does anyone know how to configure Win7 so it does not try to fix broken shortcuts?